# Error on toISOSTring() object doesn't support property or method 'toISOString'

Tags: 2010, javascript

I have tried almost everything I found on this forum but issue is not resolved. Code is working fine on Chrome but not in IE 11 (windows 7) which is used by everyone in company who will use my application. Here is the code where debugger throws an error

```
var toDay = new Date();

toDay = toDay.toISOString();
```

Here is the whole script

```
function Update() {
debugger;  
var access;
var accessCol;
var userAction;
if($("#drpAppList option:selected").val() == "Select")
{
    alert("Please select the Application list");
    return;
}
if($('input[name=chkAccess]').attr('checked'))
{
    access = true;
    userAction = "Access Process";
}
else if($('input[name=chkRevokeAccess]').attr('checked'))
{
    access = false;
    userAction = "Revoke Process";
}

var applicationListName = $("#drpAppList option:selected").text();
accessCol = $("#drpAppList option:selected").text();

var toDay = new Date();
toDay = toDay.toISOString();

//var year = toDay.getFullYear().toString();
//var month = 1 + toDay.getMonth();
//var day = toDay.getDate().toString();

//var strDate =     month + "-" + day + "-" + year; 

UpdateListItem(masterItemId,masterListName, accessCol,access,toDay);
debugger;
var appListItemId = GetItemId(applicationListName, $('input[name=txtUID]').val());
//alert(appListItemId);
if(appListItemId == undefined)
{
    appListItemId = CreateNewItem(applicationListName, masterName, masterUID, masterDepartment, toDay, access);
    //alert("New " +appListItemId);
}
else{
UpdateListItem(appListItemId,applicationListName, "AppStatus",access,toDay);
}

if (document.getElementById("inputFile").files.length != 0) {

ItemFileSubmit(applicationListName, appListItemId);  
} 
   alert(applicationListName + " Application " + userAction + "Completed");
   window.location.reload(); 
}
```

Comment: ``new Date().toISOString();`` is standard ES-5. Test if Date is overloaded in your IE11 browser by another script. Open a non SharePoint site console and ``new Date().toISOString()`` should work

Comment: When the second line executes it simply assigns 'undefined' to the variable.

Comment: @DannyEngelman yes 'new Date().toISOString()' works on console but inside script its just assigning 'undefined'

Comment: So something else is overloading Date...

Comment: I am trying to pass "todays" date as an argument to a JavaScript function which updates the date column in a list. Since toISOString() is not working, Is there any way I can do it manually? I mean converting date to string and then back to date inside my function

Comment: post your whole script.

Comment: Just posted the whole script. One thing I am working on client side and have no control over server side as our team sitting in Italy manages the server side so do you think it can be something to do with that. As when I execute    new Date().toISOString(); on non sharepoint site on console, this function works but same thing on console in sharepoint throws the error.

Comment: open F12 Dev Tools Sources tab and open **all** scripts; then Ctrl-F search for ``toISOString``. Most likely some other script is overriding the default definition

Comment: @DannyEngelman I used the following script from json.js to override and it worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Moreover I think this solution should work, i case of any browser incompatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Reference: [json.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js#L48)

```
if (!Date.prototype.toISOString) {
// Here we rely on JSON serialization for dates because it matches 
// the ISO standard. However, we check if JSON serializer is present 
// on a page and define our own .toJSON method only if necessary
if (!Date.prototype.toJSON) {
    Date.prototype.toJSON = function (key) {
        function f(n) {
            // Format integers to have at least two digits.
            return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n;
        }

        return this.getUTCFullYear()   + '-' +
            f(this.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '-' +
            f(this.getUTCDate())      + 'T' +
            f(this.getUTCHours())     + ':' +
            f(this.getUTCMinutes())   + ':' +
            f(this.getUTCSeconds())   + 'Z';
    };
}

Date.prototype.toISOString = Date.prototype.toJSON;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint has a .format method on the String prototype, so

```
 var toDate=String.format("{0:yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ}",new Date());
```

gets you an ISO date as well.

But be aware, if the original `new Date().toISOString()` does not work, it **is** an indication something not right is going on in A script someplace.
If it was my environment I would not sleep until I knew what was causing it.